# Cannot Switch HTML5 Audio SRC

Tags: blackberry, src, html5-audio

All,
I have a web app that streams audio in html5/javascript/css
When I start it and select a stream, that stream plays as expected.
When I attempt to switch from that stream to another url, the program gets to the point where the new url is bufferred, but nothing plays. I don't hear anything. Any idea what may be going on here? 
This behavior occurs on the actual smartphone device. It does not occur when I run the program in Chrome.
Here's my code:

```
//global audio variable here
var audio = new Audio;
audio.setAttribute("autoplay","autoplay");
//Then within an function in the same jscipt file, I set the url. It's                  
//when this runs a second time with a different url that it stalls.
audio.pause();
audio.setAttribute("src", "");
audio.setAttribute("src", result.rows.item(q).url_);
audio.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `audio.load();` you need to call `audio.play();`